# How can I setup Clion for NodeJS C++ Addons

Tags: node.js, cmake, clion

How can I properly configure CMAKE so that it builds my NodeJs C++ Addon (Clion).

My current cmake file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(NAME)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_library(NAME SHARED fake.cpp)

add_custom_target(build_addon
        COMMAND node-gyp build
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Building Node.js addon"
)
add_dependencies(NAME build_addon)
include_directories(
        C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
)
```

This works by compiling a fake file, but when I get an debugging information corrupted error from node-gyp there is no real way to rebuild it so I have to go and write the commands in the terminal.
Is there a better way to do this
I also tried

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT build/Release/addon.node
        COMMAND node-gyp rebuild
        COMMENT "Rebuilding"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

But I don't know how to trigger it only if there is  a specific error on the output

Comment: Is the problem that `build_addon` isn't getting rebuilt when you want? I'm confused. If that is the case, take a look at `add_custom_command`.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, it is not getting rebuilt when build fails with an error that just means you need to rebuild. How would I run the custom command?

Comment: sorry I'm having difficulty understanding what you just said. what exactly is erroring? what is not getting rebuilt? as for `add_custom_command`, you can find its docs here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html

Comment: Node-gyp is a tool that builds node addon files using another build tool.  It uses information from the old addon files so it does not have to recompile the same thing. Sometimes it throws an error saying that the old info is corrupt, even though it is not. To make the error go away you need to run rebuild instead of build. I need help making it auto-detect when that happens and run rebuild. I'll check out add custom command later, Thanks.

Comment: `add_custom_command` Did not help

Comment: can you please [edit] your question to show what you tried with `add_custom_command`?